# Bucket size smaller than total size of files on drive - are buckets compressed?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am sure this is a very dumb question.

I have backed up just over 4 terabytes of data to a google cloud bucket.

When I do a gsutil du -sh of the bucket, it is reporting 2.66 TiB.

Is there some sort of compression happening here? This has been uploaded from a Synology NAS, and when I spot check folders, all files seem to be there.

Comment: Can you share how did you upload the files?

Comment: Are you comparing the same units? gsutil reports in tebibytes, which is 1024^4. Are you possibly comparing that to terabytes, which is 1000^4?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I used the Synology cloud sync app. It seems to do a great job and reported that it was all up to date.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Thanks for the reply Mike. I did initially think that, but a tebibyte is approximately 1.1 terabytes. That conversion still leaves me 1tb away.

Comment: I think I will download a largish folder from GCS to see if it matches my local copy.

Comment: Can you confirm that Synology cloud sync app is not compressing the data? Because Cloud Storage per default does not compress the data.

Comment: @NibrassH I don't think so as the file extensions do not change. When I download the odd file here and there, they behave as normal.

Comment: Do you have a way to determine if all the 4Tb were uploaded to Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: @NibrassH The backup sync program on the NAS reports being up to date. Apart from downloading all of the data and doing a compare, that is all I am relying on.

Comment: I understand that you have observed that the backup sync program on NAS is working as expected. So in this case, we would need to inspect the your bucket and more configurations in order to determine the issue. So please contact the [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support).

Comment: @NibrassH thank you for your replies, much appreciated.